# Format keynote slides with specific conditions

Tags: automation, applescript, keynote

I am new to AppleScript'ing. Need your help to achieve my task.

I want to automate formatting my keynote.

[Below is the sample keynote slide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DaEhp.png)

My requirement is:

My AppleScript should loop each of the rows and

1. If it see "Bullet" it should get "**Bullet**"(bold)
2. Any extra new lines should be deleted.

Can anyone please help?

Thanks, Javeed